# CSS transition snaps on left side when max-width changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I have a simple `'.full-width'` class that I'm adding and removing to a `<nav>` when the user scrolls past a banner. The goal is to gradually expand or shrink the `<nav>` when the user scrolls above or below the banner. As you can see from the example CSS, the nav has the `transition` property set.

For some reason, the `<nav>` is snapping back on the left side when the bar expands. The bar still transitions correctly on the right side, and shrinking the bar works perfectly.

Interestingly, this appears to work fine with Bootstrap 3, but something in Bootstrap 4 is causing the navbar to snap.

Anyone see something I'm missing?

```js
var NAVBAR_HEIGHT_IN_PX = 50;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var bottomOfBannerContainer =
      $('.banner-container').offset().top +
      $('.banner-container').outerHeight(true) -
      NAVBAR_HEIGHT_IN_PX;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= bottomOfBannerContainer) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('container');
      $('#navbar').removeClass('full-width');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').addClass('full-width');
      $('#navbar').removeClass('container');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.banner-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px !important;
  background: blue;
}

.full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse full-width">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello S/O!</a>
</nav>

<div id="content" class="container">
  <div class="text-center col-xs-12 banner-container">workplz</div>

<p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br><p>Content!</p><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the snapping was somehow related to the sudden addition or removal of the `max-width` property. Simply adding `max-width` to `.container-fliud` has everything transitioning beautifully with the following jquery:

```
let bottomOfBannerContainer =
  $('.banner-container').offset().top +
  $('.banner-container').outerHeight(true) -
  NAVBAR_HEIGHT_IN_PX;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (Ember.$(document).scrollTop() >= bottomOfBannerContainer) {
    $('#navbar').addClass('container');
    $('#navbar').removeClass('container-fluid');
  } else {
    $('#navbar').addClass('container-fluid');
    $('#navbar').removeClass('container');
  }
});
```

and the following simple css change:

```
.container-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help: you can surround the `navbar` with the added `container` class on scroll instead of adding it directly to the `navbar`.

```js
var NAVBAR_HEIGHT_IN_PX = 50;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var bottomOfBannerContainer =
    $('.banner-container').offset().top +
    $('.banner-container').outerHeight(true) -
    NAVBAR_HEIGHT_IN_PX;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= bottomOfBannerContainer) {
      $('#navbar').addClass('container');
    } else {
      $('#navbar').removeClass('container');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
.banner-container {
  min-height: 150px;
  background: url(http://backbonejs.org/docs/images/backbone.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 70px 30px 20px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello S/O!</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="banner-container"></div>
<div class="container">1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
  with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived1500s,
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived1500s,
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived1500s,
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived1500s,
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived1500s,
  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
  the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
  Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
  Start Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
  publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
  took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
  sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
  standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
  and typesetting Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
  book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
  desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
  printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
  Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
  the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
  unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
  of the printing and typesettingLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
  make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
  and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
  1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
  with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
  remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum
  is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
  not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
  like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Upon closer look, this causes the navbar to be a bit smaller than I'd hope. I have edited the example code to show what I mean. Adding the `'.content'` class to the navbar gains it an extra 15px padding on either side, making the innards of the navbar align with the content, while the bar itself is slightly larger than the content itself. Adding a wrapping div with the `'.container'` class lines the bar itself up with the content.